# Update mysql database when google map marker move

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Well, I've a Google map where all latitude and longitude comes from DB and it's show each position with Marker. The marker is **movable.**

Now I want to update the db for latitude and longitude when i move each marker. is it possible with php or javascript or Ajax. Can you give me a solutions or suggestions ? Thank You.

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>        
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gmap3.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#map').gmap3({
      map:{
        options:{
          center:[23.709920999999998,90.40714299999999],
          zoom: 15
        }
      },
      marker:{
        values:[            
        <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from parkings where userid != '0'");
        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                            $id = $res['locId'];
            $lat = $res['latitude'];
            $long = $res['longitude'];              
            ?>
            {address:"<?php echo $lat;?>,<?php echo $long;?>"},
            <?php
            }
        ?>                               
        ],
        options:{
          draggable: true
        },
        events: {
          click: function(marker, event, context){
            markerSelected(context.id);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    $("#bcolor").click(function(){
      var marker = $('#map').gmap3({get: $("#markerId .value").text() });
      marker.setIcon(marker.getIcon() ? "" : "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles
/marker_green.png");
    });

    $("#bremove").click(function(){
      $('#map').gmap3({clear: $("#markerId .value").text() });
      $("#data").hide();
      $("#title").show();
    });

  });

  function markerSelected(id){
    var marker = $('#map').gmap3({get:id});

    $("#markerId .value").text(id);
    $("#latitude .value").text(marker.getPosition().lat());
    $("#longitude .value").text(marker.getPosition().lng());

    $("#data").show();
    $("#title").hide();
  }

</script>
```

**Html Body part code**

```
<div id="map" class="gmap3"></div>
```

When I click on each marker it's show latitude and longitude to following section :

```
<div id="latitude">
        <span class="label">Latitude : </span>
        <span class="value"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="longitude">
        <span class="label">Longitude : </span>
        <span class="value"></span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move a marker, you can get the new latitude and longitude values with jQuery.

Just add an ID to the tags containing the values :

```
<div id="latitude">
    <span class="label" id="gmap_latitude">Latitude : </span>
    <span class="value"></span>
</div>
<div id="longitude">
    <span class="label" id="gmap_longitude">Longitude : </span>
    <span class="value"></span>
</div>
```

Thus you can easily select them with jQuery and get their values.

Now, to update the database, i suggest creating a PHP script updating the database, and using an AJAX call with the jQuery load function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/‎) every time your markers are updated. You can track this using a jQuery event handler.

Comment: good idea but it's easier to just add listeners to the drop event of the marker isn't it?

Comment: @Theox, Thanks for your great idea!. First of all each lat and long has unique Mysql database id(locId). So I think I have to get each id when marker move. right ? How ?

Comment: I think you can use pythonian29033's idea to listen to the drop event of the marker. Then you can get the ID of the moved marker, and probably its latitude/longitude too, and do the AJAX call.

Comment: @Theox i don't understand pythonian29033's idea. Now if i get the DB id value of each lat and long then i think i can update the db. could you tell me how can i do this ?

Comment: Your markers are draggable, so there must be an event when you drop them. For example : 

    $(".marker").on("dropout", function() {    });

Comment: Well, I got it but having one problem that is when i move the marker then it's not showing the new lat and long. If i click on it then it's showing lat and long. So how can show the lat and long when i move it ?